# How to update value of an input with onChange in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a problem with updating the value of the input in reactjs.
I succeeded to get data from the database in the input, but I can't remove the text or add another text. to understand it better please take a look at the picture below[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLbBX.png).

and this is the code.

```
  const editPost = async (id) => {
    const data = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3007/posts/byId/${id}`, {
      headers: { accessToken: localStorage.getItem("accessToken") },
    });
    setPostObject({
      postTitle: data.data.postTitle,
      postText: data.data.postText,
    });
  };
```

and this is how I set up my inputs

```
        <input
          value={postObject.postText}
          onChange={handleUpdating}
/>
```

any suggestions will appreciate.
thank you

Comment: Please show `handleUpdating`

Comment: need to see the handleUpdating

Comment: const handleUpdating = () => {
    // setPostObject.e.target.postTitle;
    // setPostObject.e.target.postText;
  } but this is empty yet

Comment: @MohammadKhan thanks, I just added next to your comment

Comment: @John may I see your backend data? the nodejs one

Comment: sure:
router.put("/postTitle", validateToken, async (req, res) => {
  const { newTitle, newText, id } = req.body;
  await Posts.update({ postTitle: newTitle, postText: newText}, 
                     { where: { id: id } });
  res.json("post updated successfully!", newTitle, newText);
});

Comment: ...ok, it's empty? How do you expect anything to work with an empty onChange handler? Get the input to work first, worry about saving it to the db later cc @MohammadKhan

Comment: that's why I ask for it!

Comment: @John u use restapi right?

Comment: I am using MySQL for the backend and getting data through localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just necessary to set `postText` on `handleUpdating` (that, according to your comment, is empty).
Something like:

```
const handleUpdating = (e) => { 
   setPostObject({
      postTitle: postObject.postTitle,
      postText: e.target.value,
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i so now i can remove the text and add another text.. but when i submit I has a rror

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'postTitle' of null

Comment: @John can you show me submit function? Edit your question or, if you prefer, make another question and give me the link please.

Comment: No, don't make a new question.

Comment: @ChrisG sorry why?

Comment: Because just like this question, it has existing answers all over the internet. Creating a controlled input is part of the official React tutorial. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593

Comment: Hey @GiovanniEsposito sorry for the late response, actually I don't know how to submit the updated data in reactjs if just gave a quick way to do that i will appreciate you help:)